# Sphinx fails to import subpackages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I have a project directory structured like so:

```
|--sphinx
   |--mypackage
     |--__init__.py
     |--core
        |--__init__.py
        |--program.py
        |--foo.py
     |--factory
        |--__init__.py
        |--basefactory.py
```

First, I run the `sphinx-apidoc` with the following paramters from command line:

```
c:\Debug\sphinx>sphinx-apidoc -o "C:\Debug\Sphinx" "C:\Debug\Sphinx\mypackage" -f --full
```

This creates the folder structure, .bat and .rst files, etc., within the "output" directory. Good so far.

[image]

When I try to run the `make html`, I get errors/warnings, indicating:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'mypackage'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'mypackage'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'core.foo' from module 'mypackage'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'mypackage'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'core.program' from module 'mypackage'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'mypackage'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'core' from module 'mypackage'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'mypackage'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'factory.basefactory' from module 'mypackage'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'mypackage'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'factory' from module 'mypackage'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'mypackage'
```

Other similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324393/sphinx-build-fail-autodoc-cant-import-find-module), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963631/failed-to-import-module-when-building-the-sphinx-documentation), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531825/sphinx-is-not-able-to-import-anything)) suggest modifying the `sys.path.insert` statement in the `conf.py` file.

I have tried using:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath)
```

But the results are the same.

If I add the package's root path (`sys.path.insert(0, 'c:\debug\sphinx')`, I get fewer errors from Sphinx, this time only related to thee subpackages `core` and `factory`:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'program' from module 'mypackage.core'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'foo'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'basefactory' from module 'mypackage.factory'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'core'
```

Ultimately, I can get this to produce the dox by inserting ALL of the paths in the `conf.py` file:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'c:\debug\sphinx')
sys.path.insert(0, 'c:\debug\sphinx\mypackage')
sys.path.insert(0, 'c:\debug\sphinx\mypackage\core')
sys.path.insert(0, 'c:\debug\sphinx\mypackage\factory')
```

But it seems like I'm doing something wrong here. Is there a *single* path I can add to `sys.path` that will let this work without import errors? Should I have to hardcode all of the paths to package/subpackages? Or if not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can continue to keep adding to `sys.path`, but alternatively you could *install* the packages (i.e. using `setuputils.setup`). That way your packages will reside where they can be imported by any module.

Comment: the actual (non MCVE) code is managed as part of a VSTO solution and is necessarily contained in its project folders/etc. Will that matter?

Comment: What does VSTO stand for?

Comment: VSTO = Visual Studio

Comment: @mzjn if that was a problem, I'd be getting an actual error, not a warning from the `make` process. The paths, *exactly as given above* are producing the documentation as-expected.

Comment: @mzjn Right. Sphinx can't find the modules. This has nothing to do with whether I assign a raw string or an ordinary string. As given (not raw string), there are no warnings raised. My question is not about that. It's about what path(s) I should provide, or whether there's a way to do this without supplying *every* subpackage's full path.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's in VSTO. You have to have some way of doing the install, though (you can probably set it up so that you press f10 in VS and it works...but admittedly I am not familiar with VS). Colloquially `setup` is called from `setup.py`, usually like `python setup.py install` from shell. You can read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html, and there are some SO answers about it too.

Comment: And I meant `setuptools.setup`, not `setuputils` ;). Mixed up `distutils` and `setuptools` in the old brain...

Comment: were you able to solve this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Honestly, no idea if I resolved this or not. That was 3+ years ago, sorry.